# searching for PDF converter supporting many input types

Tags: c#, pdf-generation

In our company, we develop a program for our clients that takes files and transfer it to us.

We need to support many types of files to silently convert to pdf (for signing). We've used, until now, pdf creator, but it's not stable and has many bugs.

We want to buy a .dll that can do things like dynamicpdf (very expensive), as developing it ourselves will take to long.

This solution needs to support image types like jpeg, gif, bmp, tiff, html, htm, mht and many more.

Any thoughts on viable solutions to automate the creation of PDFs?

Comment: I have good references from: [http://itextpdf.com/](http://itextpdf.com/)

Comment: itext demand a lot of development , no?

Comment: we used dynamic pdf in the end

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try printing them to a Postscript file, and then converting the PS file to a PDF. I think both those problems are a lot simpler:

For printing you can use the print functions of the programs which normally edit/view those files.

For converting PS->PDF there are lots of standard tools.

Comment: what do you mean by the first step, do you have example or article

Comment: I mean you can use firefox to print html, use an image viewing program to print images (to ps), etc. It's still not trivial or anything, but I would say that problem is easier to solve than how to convert it to pdf, as each format is printable in some way.

Comment: the program run in our client servers , i cant tell them to install firefox , and other programs..

Answer (score 0):

Shameless plug, as I worked on this product, but try the [PDF Conversion Services](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-Services/summary.aspx). Scalable, reliable, optimised for server use, adds new formats all the time ([see new DXF and DWG support](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2011/02/converting-autocad-dxf-dwg-files-using.html)), supports watermarking, PDF Security etc. Has a web services based interface, so works well with C#, Java and many other platforms.

[Code sample here](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/12/converting-office-files-to-pdf-format.html).

Comment: it is not shameless if you deliver a good product. (not cheep also) i will try it. thaks