# .Net Component to convert all the major file formats to PDF

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, pdf-generation

I'm looking for a .net component (Open source or commercial) which can convert all the major frequently used file formats to PDF without making use of a print driver. I'm looking for a support for the following file formats

1. MS word (doc, docx)
2. MS Excel (xls, xlsx)
3. MS PowerPoint (ppt, pptx)
4. Major Image formats
5. HTML to pdf
6. txt, rtf etc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/598980/generation-pdf-from-html-component-for-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main products that I'm aware of is [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/). You'll probably need the following

- Aspose.Words
- Aspose.Cells
- Aspose.Slides
- Aspose.PDF
- Aspose.PDFKit

Comment: Just realised, I'm not sure it handles Images standalone, but probably within the other packages.

Answer (score 1):

Google search lead me to [this](http://www.aspose.com/categories/product-family-packs/aspose.total-product-family/default.aspx)

and you may check [DevExprees](http://www.devexpress.com/) Team to see if the got something helpful

Comment: We have already evaluated Aspose and it is great. But it is very costly.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use [GemBox.Document](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/overview) and [GemBox.Spreadsheet](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/overview). They are able to work with most document and spreadsheet files. Take a look and see if they suit you. There are free versions as well.

Answer (score 0):

The following MSDN document may help: [Saving Word 2007 Documents to PDF and XPS Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412305%28office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: What's 'this'?  Please provide some information describing this link.

Answer (score 0):

as someone who spent time looking for such a solution for my company's product--I can tell you that you are not going to find one.  It does not exist.  Sorry, dude. :(

Comment: I can't find rtf to pdf converter

Answer (score 0):

This question is [almost identical to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135102/searching-for-pdf-converter-supporting-many-input-types/5136275#5136275). So I have repeated my reply to that one below.

> Shameless plug, as I worked on this
>   product, but try the [PDF Conversion
>   Services](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-Services/summary.aspx). Scalable, reliable,
>   optimised for server use, adds new
>   formats all the time ([see new DXF and
>   DWG support](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2011/02/converting-autocad-dxf-dwg-files-using.html)), supports
>   watermarking, PDF Security etc. Has a
>   web services based interface, so works
>   well with C#, Java and many other
>   platforms.
>
> [Code sample here](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/12/converting-office-files-to-pdf-format.html).

Comment: Do you have a .NET DLL? I do not want to install any services but need a DLL.

Answer (score 0):

To output any format of file to another format requires the interpretation of the file, an in some cases proprientary formats, then a rendering of that into a new format. Most of these converters use printer drivers with existing API's etc to print to a PostScript Driver (available on most machines) then converting the PS file to PDF, which can be done via GhostScript.

Most Office documents (and supporting formats, txt, html etc) can be done this way, via office automation or using products that provide better API's. You may even be able to print directly to PDF in this case.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly cheaper, though not comprehensive product is [Solid Documents](http://www.soliddocuments.com/). We're using it and it handles office xml formats without automation, though it does automate when you give it a binary office document.